# Is it possible to retrieve campaign and adgroup detailed change history?

Tags: google-ads-api

Kindly help me to know about - How can we able to get the Campaign and Ad Group created by, created time stamp, modified by, modified time stamp(exactly detailed change history) and whether changes made via automated rules, AdWords API, and AdWords Editor?. through Google AdWords API call.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is still not possible to get a change history through the AdWords API.

The last update I found was [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adwords-api/pJxPuD1IKOQ/BNgMQGBCGQAJ) on 2016-02-11.